# How to update data from listview if the condition were met android java

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, arraylist

Hi Iam creating this app were you input Name and it automatically put the Time-inon the listview with current time. Now, if the user were to put the same Name, the system then recognized it to avoid duplication.
Here is the code for condition

```
                    getTime();
                    String fnlAddName = finalTextName+"\n"+formattedDate+"\n"+strTime;
                    if (names.indexOf(finalTextName) > -1){
                        //the system recognized the same input
                        String beforeName = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        names.add(beforeName+"\n"+strTime);
                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else{
                        names.add(fnlAddName);
                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.cancel();
                        position = position+1;
                    }
```

Now, I already achieved to detect same input from the user. What I want now is, I want to take that same data from the list (with also the time) and add another current time. So the list must update from "Name+1stCurrentTime" to "Name+1stCurrentTime+2ndCurrentTime"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look something like this

```
        if (names.indexOf(finalTextName) > -1){
            //the system recognized the same input
            int index = names.indexOf(finalTextName);

            names.set(index, names.get(index) + "\n" + strTime);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            names.add(fnlAddName);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.cancel();
            position = position+1;
        }
```

With the `indexOf` method you can get the position of the list that contains the name, then we replace it, I hope this helps you.